# How can we choose different sizes for letters and numbers?

Tags: fontsize

I want to use, for the same file, the `\normalsize` for the letters, so for the text in words, and the `\footnotesize` for the numbers. How can it be possible ?

I give an example for illustrating the goal of this purpose. In the first page of my (arabic) index (on the top right-corner, don't matter for the language!) the numbers are too great and it seems not beautiful at all... so I changed the size (in the .ind file) of the numbers, here 483--480 in scriptsize mode, which looks clearly better. How can I do this (i.e. write it in scriptsize mode) for the other numbers of the index ?

[image]

**Update 2**

My exact commands for the choice of fonts are

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\let\arabicfonttt\ttfamily
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}
```

Comment: This would break the view of the document, in my opinion. Numbers are too small then. (personal opinion)

Comment: It's probably possible with LuaLaTeX, but I don't think it's advisable. Please tell us something about the use case of your plan.

Comment: By far the safest way is to mark up the change so `one two three \mynumber{123} four` where `\mynumber` is defined as `\newcommand\mynumber[1]{{\footnotesize#1}}` (but this would look odd, do you require numbers mid-text like this, or is it a structural numbering such as line numbers?)

Comment: I use Xelatex and the font "Traditional arabic" where the numbers are too great with respect to the letters, so my idea is to review this magnification

Comment: Are the numbers coming from the same font as the text? If so, I would try to find a better designed font.

Comment: I think that the numbers can be from a different font...

Comment: see the update 2 of my post

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but rather a suggestion: Why not using Arabic numbers instead of Latin ones? I.e., `۱۲۳` instead of `123`. The text and the numbers in your document are visually incompatible and changing the font size makes it only less incompatible.

Comment: I'm obliged to use this numbers 123...

Comment: two things not mentioned in the question ... the `--` for a number-span dash is not being ligatured into an en-dash; and i am seriously disconcerted by the direction of the commas, which really should be curving to the right, not the left.  there really is a problem with the font configuration used for the numbers, though i can't say what.  but i suspect that all three problems are related.

Comment: The commas are like this because the Arabic language writes from right to left and all is inversed. I don' t understand the problem for en-dash..